# Elastic Search Exception while storing data

Tags: java, exception, elasticsearch, apache-storm

I'm trying to index a realtime steam using Storm and ElasticSearch and I'm getting this exception. I'm using the following version of ElasticSearch

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>0.90.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any pointers about where I should start looking ?

```
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
    Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:171)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:125)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:107)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected end of block data
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1370)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:499)
        at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:913)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:499)
        at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:913)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1796)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:169)
        ... 23 more
```

Comment: I also have the same problem. :/

Comment: I have this issue in 1.4.2. and in my case index, delete will not a problem,.... and while doing script update i am facing this same issue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to 0.90.1 on all my clients and servers and it works now. I"m not sure if this was the root cause or something else. If I see that error again in the new version I'll post an update here.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>0.90.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How can I make that upgrade ?

Comment: Change version in your pom.xml or other build file to match version of elastic search running on your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was something I was doing with the data. I was creating an index with document type as `_tweet`. Elasticsearch doesn't allow `_` in the beginning of the type.

I suggest you do `elasticsearch -f -D es.config=config/elasticsearch.yml` to start the service in foreground. Then you can read the error to see why you get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to check if the elastic search client and server are running the same version. I was using a 0.90.5 server with a 0.90.3 client and was able to get rid of the exception when I upgraded my Java client to 0.90.5